# Secondary Template for Structure

Tags: templating, routing

I created a Profile structure for my client's employees. He asked if I could generate an email signature for them from their Profile. I figured out a way to put all the signatures on one page using a

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('profiles') %}
```

loop on a single page.

However, is there a way to give each person their own page for an email signature? `/PROFILE/email-signature` that pulls content from the profile. I want this to update dynamically as he adds/removes employees.

How would I create a secondary template for the profiles for an email-signature?

Comment: Are you just asking how to create the details template for an entry in your structure like `/profiles/john-doe` ? Or are you asking how to have both `/profiles/john-doe` AND `/profiles/john-doe/email-signature` and they are both connected to one "John Doe" profiles entry?

Comment: The second question... I need an email-signature page for every profile page, but still keep the profile pages.

Comment: Ah, that's just a dynamic routes issue then. Solution is posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create a dynamic route by going to **Settings > Routes > "New Route"**.  Then you'd set your custom route to `profiles/{slug}/email-signature` and decide which template to serve when the url looks that way.

You can either serve the `_entry` template you're serving for `/profiles/john-doe` or create a new one. Depending on the situation, you may need to set the entry in the template like...

```
{% set person = craft.request.getSegment(2) %}
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('profiles').slug(person).first %}
```

...in the event Craft can't figure it out because you're on a separate template.  Grabbing segment 2 means you're grabbing `john-doe` from the URL, which will help Craft know which entry to find.

Here's more info on routing in the docs: https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment on Ryan's answer, but I don't have the necessary reputation to post it.

If you're using a custom route like `profiles/{slug}/email-signature` then you don't need to use `getSegment(2)` to access the person. The whole point is that your setting the `slug` variable during the routing so should be able to just use `{{ slug }}` in the template that the route is pointed at.

So you'd just need:
`{% set entry = craft.entries.section('profiles').slug(slug).first %}`