# How can I break up a product into two page templates?

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce, products

I have a product overview page, with images and some text, then a call to action that launches a product customiser for that particular product. (the customiser is requiring some bespoke JSON using line items).
It is on the product customise page that the 'add to cart' button is placed.

I would like the following URLS for each seperate page:

*Product overview:*

```
myshop.com/products/productname
```

*Product customiser:*

```
myshop.com/products/productname/customise/
```

How would I go about doing this? By default, Craft only seems to let me use one template per product.

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to create a [dynamic route](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes) to either ignore `customise/` in the url or serve up a different template altogether.

See my answer on this ticket for more information. [Secondary Template for Structure](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21951/secondary-template-for-structure/21994#21994)

Comment: Excellent thank you Ryan. this looks like the way to go :)